# Gas cost for contract transaction called form external

Tags: solidity, contract-development, transactions, ether, gas

If I call my contract and ask it to send x amount of ether to another account y, I know i have to pay a transaction cost.

Will the contract also have to pay any amount while sending the ether to the account y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the gas will be paid for by you, the sender of the transaction. The gas will not be taken from the contract.